# How to Customize Reactstrap button in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, in that project I am using Reactstrap. In that I have one Button

Drop down. For that Button Drop down the heading is Select Dropdown, If I click drop down then I

Will get options so If I select those options my heading has to replace those options in heading.

This is App.js

`````````
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';


function App(props) {
  const [dropdownOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setOpen(!dropdownOpen);
  return (
    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Select Dropdown
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>First Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Third Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </ButtonDropdown>
  );
}

export default App;

````````



If you feel I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.
`````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropdown is not supposed to show the selected value as header UX wise. May be you are looking for Select box. Anyway you can acheive what you are looking for using a react state.

```
function App(props) {
  const [dropdownOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [header, setHeader] = useState('Select Dropdown');

  const toggle = () => setOpen(!dropdownOpen);
  return (
    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        {header}
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => setHeader('First Action')}>First Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => setHeader('Third Action')}>Third Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </ButtonDropdown>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is an uncontrolled component now. Make it controllable.

Add another state to hold the value of the selected option. Try this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';


function App(props) {
  const [dropdownOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [action, setAction] = useState(null);

  const toggle = () => setOpen(!dropdownOpen);
  return (
    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        {action || 'Select Dropdown'}
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => setAction('First Action')>
           First Action
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => setAction('Third Action')>
          Third Action
        </DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </ButtonDropdown>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Here it will show 'Select Dropwon' by default and the selected action
>   when the action got selected.